# Sum of two arrays using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sum

I am trying to create a program in C that calculates the sum of two int arrays using pointers.
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4}
int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
int c[] = sumArrays(a,b,4,6)
Output : c = {2,4,6,8,5,6}
```

The problem is my output is different, it shows:

```
Output : c = {2,4,6,8}
```

Any idea what did I do wrong and how to correct it ?
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* sumArrays(int *arr1, int *arr2, int dim1,int dim2)
{
    int *ret = NULL;

    if(dim1<dim2) ret = (int*) malloc(dim2*sizeof(int));
    else ret =  (int*) malloc(dim1*sizeof(int));
    if(ret)
    {
        if(dim1<dim2) {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < dim1;i++) {
                ret[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
            }
            for (i = dim1; i < dim2;i++) {
                ret[i]=arr2[i];
            }   
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < dim2;i++) {
                ret[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
            }
            for (i = dim2; i < dim1;i++) {
                ret[i]=arr1[i];
            } 
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


int main()
{
int *a[] = {1,2,3,4};
int *b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

int *c = sumArrays(a,b,4,6);
printf("c = ");
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(c); i++) {
    printf("%d,",c[i]);
} 
}
```

Comment: Don't flag C++, else, you will have to use `std::vector`.

Comment: You also need to change `int *a[]` to `int a[]`.

Comment: On another note, you should be getting `c = {2,4,6,8,}`, not `c = {2,4,6,8}`

Comment: Btw, the code is incorrect. It could lead to undefined behaviour. You are allocating some memory inside a function and when you go out of its scope, who knows. Never do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sizeof c will always return 4 for 32-bit system and 8 for 64-bit, because c is a pointer to int.

So to print the result array you should write:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```

Comment: That is so obvious.. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You have problem about using pointers.

```
int *a[] = {1,2,3,4};      // a is an array of pointers to integers.
int *b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};  // b is an array of pointers to integers.
```

By doing this, you are declaring `array of pointers to integers`. So, it most likely causes compiler warning or error depending on your compile settings like, *initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.* When you are passing the actual arguments to formal parameters, it causes same warning as well. Your main should be like this,

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4}; 
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int sizeA = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    int sizeB = sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b);


    int *c = sumArrays(a,b,sizeA,sizeB);
    printf("c = ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeA < sizeB ? sizeB : sizeA); i++) {
        printf("%d,",c[i]);
    }
}
```